# enqueue style using admin-ajax.php

Tags: ajax, wp-enqueue-style

Actually I’m making a generic personnal template with customization from the backend; something like in the premium themes.

So I made a “theme apearance options page” with ACF. I added fields like “h1 title” as repeater and “colors, fonts…” as subfields.

I made a specific css for my “customization theme” but to display the ACF fields I’m using a php file enqueued as stylesheet.
When I’m enter the value like “$color =’#fff'” and echo it on the css tag it’s working.

My CSS.php:

```
<?php
if( have_rows('repeater', 'option') ):                  
    while( have_rows('repeater', 'option')): the_row(); 
        $FieldColor = the_sub_field('color');           
    endwhile; 
endif; 



?>
 <!-- Begin CSS -->
h1 {color: <?php echo $FieldColor; ?>;}
```

From the ACF support,my problem seems to be we can't enqueue a php as stylesheet  like this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpchild_enqueue_styles' );

function wpchild_enqueue_styles(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'inu-media-style',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/inc/template/css-template/styles-css.php' );   
}
```

and make the functions, plugins values working. Do to that we have to enqueue the style script using admin-ajax.php .

Does  anyone knows how enqueue my file.php as CSS with admin-ajax ?

Comment: Does this need to be in a file? Can't you just output the styles in a <style> tag?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I prefere not there is a lot of fields